# C# 7 Pattern Matching

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

Suppose I have the following exception filter

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) when (e is AggregateException ae && ae.InnerException is ValueException<int> ve || e is ValueException<int> ve) {
    ...
}
```

I could have simply written two separate `catch` blocks, but I wanted to see how one could use the pattern matching feature to catch an exception that either *is* itself or is wrapped within an `AggregateException`. Here, however, the compiler complains of a redefinition of `ve`, which is understandable. I have seen a case where a pattern matched variable is reused within the same expression as shown here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

```
if (o is int i || (o is string s && int.TryParse(s, out i)) { /* use i */ }
```

so there is probably a way to do what I want. Or is there?

Comment: `i` is used there but not declared twice. it's declared once in `o is int i`, in your case you are declaring `ve` twice.

Comment: To exapand on the previous comment, `i` would be declared twice if the expression was: `(o is int i || (o is string s && int.TryParse(s, out int i)))`

Comment: As noted, the example you're referencing doesn't declare the variable twice, but you do. Try something like this instead: `(e is AggregateException ae && ae.InnerException is ValueException<int> ve || (ve = e as ValueException<int>) != null)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot declare `ve` variable twice in same scope. But you can rewrite exception filter so that variable for `ValueException<int>` will be declared only once:

```
catch(Exception e) 
  when (((e as AggregateException)?.InnerException ?? e) is ValueException<int> ve)
{
   // ...
}
```

It's your one-liner to catch exception if it either was thrown directly or if it is wrapped into `AggregateException`.

Keep in mind that purpose of `AggregateException` is consolidating multiple exceptions into one exception object. There could be several inner exceptions, and some of them can be aggregate exceptions as well. So you should flatten aggregate exception and check all of its inner exceptions.

---

You can put 'unwrapping' part into extension method to improve readability of your code.

Comment: Is there a reason to not capture AggregateException like this?

catch (AggregateException agg) when (agg.InnerException is ValueException<int> ve)
{
  //
}

Comment: @RyanHaney yes, this doesn't handle the case when the exception is ValueException<int>

Comment: Ah crap, didn't see that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Not as nice as Sergey's solution, but you can also use different names and coalesque them:

```
try 
{
    ...
} catch (Exception e) 
      when (e is ValueException<int> ve1 || 
            e is AggregateException ae  
              && ae.InnerException is ValueException<int> ve2)  
{
    var exept = ve1 ?? ve2;

    // do something with exept
}
```

if you handle InnerExceptions of ValueException or general ValueException Exceptions the same.